# About the meaning of "light smattering of applause"

Tags: phrases, adjectives

I expected "light smattering of applause" to mean "few applause" because "light" has the meaning of "small, not heavy".

However, the phrase seems to mean "a lot of applause" in the context. For example:

> The critics were so fulsome in their praise that
>   Scheinhauer, a librettist known to become squeamish after a light
>   smattering of applause, retreated from public view.

Does anyone know how to understand the meaning of *light smattering of applause*?

Comment: The example is _contrasting_ the critics' praise with a light smattering of applause, not equating the two.

Comment: It's not possible to understand the meaning of this sentence because "fulsome praise" means either "abundant praise" (positive connotation) or "nauseatingly flattering" (negative connotation) and disparaging. This is a good example of why words matter & why only intentionally devious writers, lexical ignoramuses, & linguistic idiots use ambiguity when clarity is called for. In either case, "a light smattering of applause" means that only a few people in audience clapped their hands, not that there was a lot of applause, not even in this context.

Comment: This might be a good candidate for migration to ELL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your original intepretation is correct. If Scheinhauer became squeamish after **even** a light smattering, than the more fulsome praise made him retreat entirely. "Light smattering" is used to contrast "fulsome", to mean exactly what you thought.