# Degrees of applause

Tags: expressions, expression-choice

I tried to describe varying degrees of applause:

- reserved applause
- restrained applause
- polite applause
- enthusiastic applause
- tumultuous applause
- thunderous applause

I was wondering whether there were **more common expressions to describe degrees of applause that consist of an adjective and a noun** (a [light smattering of applause](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/112385/194221) would not fall into that category).

Hereby I was also wondering whether there were **more expressions to describe enthusiastic applause that do not also imply the presence of a large group** (tumultuous and thunderous seem to be levels of noise that can only be reached with a bigger group, but not with e.g., 4 people).

Comment: "golf clap" http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/golf-clap

Comment: I can't think of anything that implies that a small group applauds enthusiastically. But I did find a significant use of 'tepid applause' to add to your list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More expressions describing enthusiastic applause without implying crowd size?  Then I humbly submit the following:

- fierce applause
- energetic applause
- fanatical applause

And another one that implies a larger crowd:

- torrential applause

Answer (score 0):

Well, some consideration should be given to what goes on in the studio recording of a TV-sitcom or variety show where a live audience is often cued in by an illuminated sign that reads **APPLAUD NOW**. It used to be the case that these recordings were preceded by a "warm-up" comedian whose job it was to get the audience into a heightened state of mirth, ready to carry over to the sitcom that followed. How would one label such manipulated applause? **Contrived** is a word that springs to mind. And then you have **canned laughter** where the same audio-clip of people laughing inanely is repeatedly edited into a TV sitcom in the hope and expectation that the TV audience at home won't realize what's going on. I find these tricks of the trade **uproarious** and no doubt **canned laughter** is capable of generating a double-punch line all by itself, with savvy people at home finding themselves convulsed by laughter at the craziness of it all. If I were in this situation at home I would encourage my family to give it the bum's rush with a **slow handclap**

**Slow handclap**: An instance of slow, rhythmic clapping by an audience as a sign of displeaure or impatience (Oxford Dictionaries online)